# Magento : Extra Add to Cart Button for Installation Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, addtocart

I have a website, sell a products with and without installation service. 
I want two add to cart buttons, one with and one without installation on a product page. The price for installation is variable for each product.

How can I create a extra add to cart button for this products? Thanks

Comment: You can do this using adding custom option to product. No requirement to add this extra button.

Answer (score 0):

write below code in {theme}/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml near Add to Cart button.

```
<?php 
    if($_product->getSampleProductId()): 
        $_price = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_product->getSampleProductId(), 'price', Mage::app()->getStore()); 
        $_formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_price, true, false);
        $_buttonTitle = "Order Sample @".$_formattedPrice;
?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $_buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/product/'.$_product->getSampleProductId()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $_buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```